# TKinter Geometry Manager displaying multiple rows of widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I wish to display a list of sentences with missing words.  The basic, one-line, idea is the following:
[image: One line example]

The construction of the above is a "label + entry + label + spacing + label".  In order to make sure that the widgets were aligned left, I used the following code:

```
phraseLabel1 = tk.Label(questionFrame)
phraseLabel1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

keyWordEntry = tk.Entry(questionFrame)
keyWordEntry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

phraseLabel2 = tk.Label(questionFrame)
phraseLabel2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

keyWordLabel = tk.Label(questionFrame)
keyWordLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=30)
```

My objective is to present the users with an input screen for multiple sentence.  As for example given in the following drawing:

[image: Example multiple lines]

Whilst I manage to create the labels via the underneath (experimental) code, I lack understanding to manage the geometry.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("myTest")
root.geometry("700x700")

questionFrame = tk.Frame(root)
resultFrame = tk.Frame(root)

for frame in (questionFrame, resultFrame):
     frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

#DB Query returning a set of phrases and Keywords
(zinPhrase1, zinPhrase2, keyWordFR, keyWordNL)=getPhrase() 

#Init 
lab1 = []
keyWordEntry = []
lab2 = []
keyWord = []


for i in range(4): #4 is entered as a dummy value

    lab1.append(tk.Label(questionFrame))    
    lab1[i].pack()

    keyWordEntry.append(tk.Entry(questionFrame))
    keyWordEntry[i].pack()

    lab2.append(tk.Label(questionFrame))    
    lab2[i].pack()

    keyWord.append(tk.Label(questionFrame))
    keyWord[i].pack()

    lab1[i].config(text=zinPhrase1[i])
    keyWordEntry[i].config(width=8)
    lab2[i].config(text=zinPhrase2[i])
    keyWord[i].config(text=keyWordNL[i],fg="red")

questionFrame.tkraise()
root.mainloop()
```

How can I manage the placement of the widgets line by line, as shown in the drawing above?   Any help would gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't seem to want to organize your widgets in a grid, the most common solution to this problem is to create a frame for each row. The frames stack top-to-bottom, and the widgets inside the frame stack left-to-right.

In my experience, GUI code is much easier to visualize when you separate widget creation from widget layout, so I've done that in the following example to hopefully make it easier to comprehend.

```
for i in range(4): #4 is entered as a dummy value
    rowFrame = tk.Frame(questionFrame)
    rowFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

    lab1.append(tk.Label(rowFrame))    
    keyWordEntry.append(tk.Entry(rowFrame))
    lab2.append(tk.Label(rowFrame))    
    keyWord.append(tk.Label(rowFrame))

    lab1[i].pack(side="left")
    keyWordEntry[i].pack(side="left")
    lab2[i].pack(side="left", padx=(0, 40))
    keyWord[i].pack(side="left")

    lab1[i].config(text=zinPhrase1[i])
    keyWordEntry[i].config(width=8)
    lab2[i].config(text=zinPhrase2[i])
    keyWord[i].config(text=keyWordNL[i],fg="red")
```

The above code results in something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Would something like the following suffice?

```
for i in range(4): #4 is entered as a dummy value
    frames.append(tk.Frame(questionFrame))
    frames[i].grid(row=i, column=0, stick='W')

for i in range(4):
    lab1.append(tk.Label(frames[i]))
    lab1[i].grid(row=0, column=0)


    keyWordEntry.append(tk.Entry(frames[i]))
    keyWordEntry[i].grid(row=0, column=1)

    lab2.append(tk.Label(frames[i]))
    lab2[i].grid(row=0, column=2)

    keyWord.append(tk.Label(frames[i]))
    keyWord[i].grid(row=0, column=3)

    lab1[i].config(text=zinPhrase1[i])
    keyWordEntry[i].config(width=8)
    lab2[i].config(text=zinPhrase2[i])
    keyWord[i].config(text=keyWordNL[i],fg="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  In my case all the fields are of variable length.  For this reason I struggle to organise the placement with the grid manager.

Comment: Edited, using four frames added to the questionnaire frame?